# spring.net how to pass System.Type as a parameter

Tags: dependency-injection, spring.net, system.type

```
public class MyClass{

public MyClass(System.Type type)
{
// do whatever
}
}
```

How do I pass SomeOtherClass type in spring.net DI? I couldn't get through that in documentation nor my implementation?
tried to do below but have an exception.. :

```
...
  <constructor-arg index="0" value="SomeOtherClass" type="System.Type"/> 
..
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<constructor-arg index="0" value="MyNamespace.SomeOtherClass, MyAssembly" />
```

Comment: this will give the class itself, and not the type of the class?

Comment: This will 100% return the `Type` of the class if you want the name of the type you could call `<constructor-arg index="0" expression="T(ConsoleApplication8.Sample, ConsoleApplication8)"/>`.